# LLDB equivalent of gdb's future-break?

Tags: objective-c, lldb, appcode

I keep a `future-break objc_exception_throw` in my .gdbinit (because I generally debug in AppCode, which doesn't yet have a GUI means of configuring breaks on objective-c exceptions).

Is there an equivalent for LLDB?

Comment: For anyone else interested in this for AppCode, note that the [114.179 EAP build](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/OBJC/AppCode+EAP) has built-in support for exception breakpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a ".lldbinit" file in the directory from which you are debugging and then specify the file on the command line:

% cat ./.lldbinit
breakpoint set --name objc_exception_throw
% lldb /bin/ls
(lldb) breakpoint list --full
Current breakpoints:
1: name = 'objc_exception_throw', locations = 0 (pending)

This should help you to work around the issue for now.

The ".lldbinit" file ordering is:

check for app specific ~/.lldbinit-lldb file (where "lldb" is the name of the application that is running the LLDB.framework, you can add a ~/.lldbinit-Xcode for Xcode only command) if available

if no app specific file from step 1, then source "~/.lldbinit" if it exists

load the file and process the options from the "lldb" command line command

parse the local "./.lldbinit" file from the current working directory.

Comment: thanks. I haven't had any luck so far getting my ~/.lldbinit read when using lldb in AppCode. It's fine from the command line though, which is good enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't currently do that with lldb.  Until lldb has set up a Target (which will happen when you specify a binary), you can't add a breakpoint.  This is something that will need to be added in the future.